# Qt / PyQt: Low level text rendering

Tags: python, qt, text, pyqt, rendering

[Note: I prefer PyQt, but an answer for Qt is the same as far as I am concerned. I understand both languages.]

Question:

I would like to render a string, for example: 'Hello *world*!' (nothing fancy). I DO NOT want to do this through a proxy, such as QTextEdit or QWebKit. Rather, I want full control of the rendering on a low level - each character. The issues/questions are:

1. Which widget should I use (for quickest rendereing) QGraphicsWidget?
2. Given a position (x,y), how do I then render an image of the character on the screen?
3. The text may span multiple lines. Should I render an image of each character to the screen one by one, or should I first create an 'image' of the line, and then render each line (I assume this would aid in the speed of scrolling, as wouldn't have to recalculate every character, only move the line up or down)? If the latter, how do I create that image?
4. How would I go about highlighting a selection as the user drags his mouse over it - would I have to rerender the character, or just do some 'background color' operation on that position of the screen?

Please, I would appreciate if you could answer in a practical manner - i.e. specific methods/classes/etc. (not just a vague idea like 'display it' - but how?).

Thanks!

Comment: That's 11 question marks in there.. Quite a lot of questions to answer at the same time. You might be more successful getting helpful answers if you try to focus on a single problem first, e.g. how to render a single character. Once you are able to do that, you can ask further questions like getting it italic or performance of rendering if you get stuck.

Comment: Understood. I've now narrowed it down to the most basic issues that must be taken into account when choosing a method of rendering.

Comment: It's much easier to give "practical" answers if you ask specific questions and provide examples of the code that's not working. Otherwise, it might seem like you are asking people to write all your code for you.

Comment: Now that skyhisi has so kindly provided me with the basic starting points, of course I will code the specifics myself, and be able to ask more pointed questions. Until now, I didn't even know where to begin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a custom `QWidget` by overloading the `QWidget::paintEvent` and using a painter is about the lowest level in Qt using the widget system.

Here is a full working example using C++ I've put together for you, I don't know PyQt but hopefully you can port this!

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef _WIDGET_H_
#define _WIDGET_H_

#include <QtGui>

class CustomPaint : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    protected:
        virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
};

#endif
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"

void CustomPaint::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* ev)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setClipRect(ev->rect());
    painter.fillRect(ev->rect(), Qt::white);

    const int x = 10;
    const int y = 10;
    const int w = width() - 20;
    const int h = height() - 20;

    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::red), 0.0, Qt::DashLine));
    painter.drawRect(x, y, w, h);

    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::black), 0.0, Qt::SolidLine));
    painter.drawText(x, y, w, h,
        Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop | Qt::TextWordWrap,
        tr("Hello World"));
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "widget.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    CustomPaint win;
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**test.pro**

```
QT=core gui
HEADERS=widget.h
SOURCES=test.cpp widget.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me some good background information about which classes and methods need to be used. Now all I have to do is play around with their specifics, as per my needs. (as per ekhumoro's comment on the question, I really appreciate the time spent answering the question, and I apologize if you felt I was asking you to write my code. I was simply looking for the basic starting points, which you provided. )